# npm pdfkittable ENOENT for reading file from locally in EC2

Tags: express, amazon-ec2, pdfkit, node-pdfkit

My **Express App** Ending up in the following **error** while running code of **pdfkittable** in **AWS EC2**, but it was **working fine in my local system**

.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './images/145.jpg'
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at Object.openSync (node:fs:585:3)
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:35)
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at getImageBuffer (/home/ec2-user/miassessment/pdf-service.js:41:15)
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at Object.miReportGenerator (/home/ec2-user/miassessment/pdf-service.js:47:25)
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at Process.reportGeneration (/home/ec2-user/miassessment/backendFuntions.js:489:20)
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: errno: -2,
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: syscall: 'open',
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: code: 'ENOENT',
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: path: './images/145.jpg'
May 17 01:51:56 ip-172-31-15-xxx my-node-server: }
```

The file is existing in /images directory inside the root directory.

Image file to read exist in

```
/miassessment/images/145.jpg
```

Code Running in

```
/miassessment/pdf-service.js
```

Comment: Try specifying the absolute path of image.  '/home/ec2-user/miassessment/images/145.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give absolute path of image `'/home/ec2-user/miassessment/images/145.jpg'` for EC2.